# Flask decorator : Can't pass a parameter from URL

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators

i'm quite new with flask and i'm trying to use the migthy power of decorators :p 
I read lot of things and found tons of topics about python decorators here but nothing really helpful.

```
@app.route('groups/<id_group>')
@group_required(id_group)
@login_required
def groups_groupIndex(id_group):
    #do some stuff
    return render_template('index_group.html')
```

This is the error i get :

```
@group_required(id_group), NameError: name 'id_group' is not defined
```

Ok, id_group is not defined yet, but I don't understand why i CAN use the id_group parameter from the URL in the function groups_groupIndex but NOT in the decorator!

I try to move/switch decorators, but the same error occure each time.

Here is my decorator, but it seems to work fine

```
def group_required(group_id):
    def decorated(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner (*args, **kwargs):
            #Core_usergroup : table to match users and groups
            groups = Core_usergroup.query.filter_by(user_id = g.user.id).all()
            for group in groups:
                #if the current user is in the group : return func
                if int(group.group_id) == int(group_id) :
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
            flash(gettext('You have no right on this group'))
            return render_template('access_denied.html')     
        return inner
    return decorated
```

Maybe i don't see decorators like i should... Can i use my decorator this way or need i rewrite something different ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You defined `group_id` as a function parameter; that makes it a local name in that function.

That doesn't make the name available to other scopes; the global namespace that the decorator lives in cannot see that name.

The *wrapper* function, however, can. It'll be passed that parameter from the `@apps.route()` wrapper when called:

```
def group_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(group_id, *args, **kwargs):
        #Core_usergroup : table to match users and groups
        groups = Core_usergroup.query.filter_by(user_id = g.user.id).all()
        for group in groups:
            #if the current user is in the group : return func
            if int(group.group_id) == int(group_id) :
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        flash(gettext('You have no right on this group'))
        return render_template('access_denied.html')     
    return wrapper
```

Note that this decorator doesn’t bother with passing on the `group_id` parameter to the decorated function; use `return func(group_id, *args, **kwargs)` instead of you still need access to that value in the view function.

Comment: I knew it was scope issue, thanks a lot, it works perfectly now :)

Comment: @anjalis and that’ll still pass in `group_id` as an explicit argument. Python unpacks arguments from a `**...` mapping when calling. If your test fails then that’s because the wrapper doesn’t pass on `group_id` to the view function.

Comment: @sudocoder: sorry, while `func` is indeed missing, the decorator here explicitly expects the decorated function to accept at least one positional argument, `group_id`. The other post you link may remove that requirement, but that's not a strict requirement to make this decorator work. If it didn't work for you, something else was wrong.

Comment: But what if the group_id is not in url params, but passed in query arguments or in the body of request?

Comment: @KarishmaSukhwani: then the argument would need to be taken from the `request` object instead.

Comment: Yes, but it varies endpoint to endpoint. some endpoints in my case are POST and I want to pass it from where I am using this decorator. Any way to take request object in decorator? I tried request.investor_id but I can't pass request in before an active HTTP context.

Comment: @KarishmaSukhwani: the `request` object is special and is available in any function as long as there is an active request. Just make the `group_id` argument a keyword argument with a default value, like `group_id=None`, and in the decorator test for that default value (`if group_id is None:`) to then look at the request for the value.

Comment: @KarishmaSukhwani: only access values on the request **during a request**, so in the wrapper function created by the decorator.

Comment: Okay, let me see a workaround for this. or else may be its not a good idea to use decorator in my case.

Comment: @KarishmaSukhwani: Please do some research, comments are not the place for follow-up questions. See [How to write Flask decorator with request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26736419) for an example using request data in a decorator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251856/discussion-between-karishma-sukhwani-and-martijn-pieters).