# How to write Flask decorator with request?

Tags: python, flask, python-decorators

I am not sure why following decorator[validate_request] doesn't work. What is  correct way to write such validation decorator?

```
def validate_request(req_type):
    if req_type is 'json' and not request.json:
        abort(400)
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_func
    return decorator

@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/<int:task_id>', methods=['PUT'])
@validate_request('json')
@json
def update_task(task_id):
#    task = filter(lambda t: t['id'] == task_id, tasks)
    task = [task for task in tasks if task['id'] == task_id]
    if len(task) == 0:
        abort(404)

    #update task
    for field in ['title', 'description', 'done']:
        task[0][field] = request.json.get(field, task[0][field])
```

Error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AGR\Programming\LearningPython\FlaskLearning\flask_rest\app.py", line 156, in <module>
    @validate_request('json')
  File "C:\AGR\Programming\LearningPython\FlaskLearning\flask_rest\app.py", line 144, in validate_request
    if req_type is 'json' and not request.json:
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 20, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of request context')
RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

How should this be done in a more idiomatic way???

Comment: you need to move the `and not request.json` part inside the decorator function, otherwise it is being evaluated at the point where the decorator is applied to the view function (i.e. at import time) rather than when the view function is being called, so there is no request object available yet

Comment: in fact just put the whole `if req_type is 'json' and not request.json:
        abort(400)` inside the decorator

Comment: request.json is deprecated anyway, use request.get_json()

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is how your decorator should look like

```
def validate_request(f):
  @functools.wraps(f)
  def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
    # Do something with your request here
    data = flask.request.get_json()
    if not data:
      flask.abort(404)
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  return decorated_function
```

and you will call it like this

```
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/<int:task_id>', methods=['PUT'])
@validate_request
def update_task(task_id):
    # The rest of your code..
```

Comment: What is actually causing the RuntimeError here?

Answer (score 12):

It's kind of an old post, but I think that it may benefit from a little correction:
`decorated_function` needs to return `f(*args, **kws)`

```
def validate_request(f):
  @functools.wraps(f)
  def decorated_function(*args, **kws):
    # Do something with your request here
    data = flask.request.get_json()
    if not data:
      flask.abort(404)
    return f(*args, **kws)
  return decorated_function
```

Otherwise you will encounter `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.`

Comment: excellent catch, I wrote it by memory and obviously it slipped away, I hope you don't mind adding the missing return to my existing answer! Cheers!

Comment: Sure! I am glad my answer helped to improve yours