# flask route decorator RuntimeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, decorator, python-decorators

I wrote a simple flask app, which returns specified id for users. I want make every route use the same logic, so I want to implement this as a decorator.

```
# the decorator
def session_decorator(data_handle_func):
     session_id = request.cookies.get('static')
    if session_id is None:
        session_id = uuid.uuid1().hex
    resp = make_response(data_handle_func(session_id))
    resp.set_cookie('static', session_id)
    return resp

# version 1
@app.route("/session")
def sessionx():
    def simple(session_id):
         return session_id
    return session_decorator(simple)

# version 2, throw excetion 
@app.route("/session2")
@session_decorator
def sessionx(session_id):
    return session_id
```

The first version works fine. The second is the desired version, which throw:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 466, in <module>
    @session_decorator
  File "app.py", line 451, in session_decorator
    session_id = request.cookies.get('static')
  File "/home/users/install/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.11-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/local.py", line 342, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/home/users/install/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.11-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/local.py", line 301, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/home/users/install/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/globals.py", line 20, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of request context')
RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

---

**UPDATE**

According to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736419/how-to-write-flask-decorator-with-request), I wrote the following decorator, which works. But I've no idea why this works, and what is actually causing the RuntimeError here? Could anyone give some suggestion on this?

```
def session_decorator_v2(data_handle_func):
    @functools.wraps(data_handle_func)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kws):
        session_id = request.cookies.get('static')
        if session_id is None:
            print "not exist"
            session_id = uuid.uuid1().hex
        resp = make_response(data_handle_func(session_id))
        resp.set_cookie('static', session_id)
        return resp
    return decorated_function
```

Comment: @KevinGuan my problem is not about `UT`.   @rmn I'll try it, once it works, I'll close this problem.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Retracted my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decorator is wrongly defined. It must be a function returning a function that will be executed and call `data_handle_func`

```
# the decorator
def session_decorator(data_handle_func):
    def session_parser():
        session_id = request.cookies.get('static')
        if session_id is None:
            session_id = uuid.uuid1().hex
        resp = make_response(data_handle_func(session_id))
        resp.set_cookie('static', session_id)
        return resp
    return session_parser

# version 2, throw excetion 
@app.route("/session2")
@session_decorator
def sessionx(session_id):
    return session_id
```

The reason you are seeing this error is because your "decorator" is executed as soon as attach to the route. And when you do `request.cookies.get('static')` Flask is crying because it does not have  a request context yet (you are initializing the application, not handling a request)

**Edit on OP's update:**
The code you provide is exactly the same that I gave you.

```
@functools.wraps(data_handle_func)
```

Is a decorator that will put the function name and description to the wrapped function. So the decorator does not change the name of lost the description when used.

A decorator is basically just a function that when applied on a function will return a function...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you mean the wrong decorator executed where initializing the app, which should be executed when handling a request.  And this lead to the error?

Comment: Yes, a decorator only returns a function that will replace the one you are decorating. The decorator is execute once, but the inner function will be executed everytime you access the decorated function.

Comment: Does the `RuntimeError working outside of request context` means that the context is not exist and will only be here when handling a context?